# ListView - обновление данных в UI handler'ом

Tags: android, listview, android-handler

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не правильно? Хандлер обновляется раз в 10 сек (вижу по логам), но данные в ListView не обновляются

```
public class FriendMsgActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView sList;
SimpleAdapter sAdapter;

ImageView avatars;

String FriendURL = "http://MySite.KZ/index.php";
String LOG_TAG = "FriendMsg Activity: ";

HashMap map;
ArrayList data;
Handler mHandler;

Context context = (Context) this;
TextView textView;
Button snd_msg;

protected String LV_KEY    = Auth.key;
protected String LV_USID   = Auth.id;
protected String LV_LOGIN  = Auth.login;
protected String LV_lsNAME = Auth.lsname;

final String LV_USID_MSG = "user_msg_id";
final String LV_MSGID = "msg_id";
final String LV_MSG = "msg";
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_msg);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.form_input);
    snd_msg  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMsgGet);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    new FriendMsgLoad().execute();
    new RefreshActivity().run();
}

// тут пытаюсь обновится
class RefreshActivity extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FriendMsgActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Сработал mHandler!");
            }
        });
    }
}

public void sendMsg(View v) {

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.form_input);
    String form_input_msg = textView.getText().toString();

    if(!form_input_msg.equals("")) {
        GetMsg getMsg = new GetMsg();
        getMsg.SendMsg(context, GET_ID, form_input_msg);
        textView.setText("");

    } else {}

}


class FriendMsgLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        byte[] data = null;
        String parammetrs = "FriendMsgLoad=true&get_id=" + GET_ID + "&us_id=" + LV_USID + "&key=" + LV_KEY;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(FriendURL);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(parammetrs.getBytes().length));
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            data = parammetrs.getBytes("UTF-8");
            os.write(data);
            data = null;

            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            return forecastJsonStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String forecastJsonStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(forecastJsonStr);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray chat = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < chat.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject msgList = chat.getJSONObject(i);

                String error = msgList.getString("error");
                if(!error.equals("0")) {
                    if(error.equals("1")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FriendActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка! Не получилось зарузить сообщения..");

                    }
                    if(error.equals("2")) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка! Не верный ключ авторизации..");
                    }
                }

                String msg = msgList.getString("msg");
                String msg_id = msgList.getString("msg_id");
                final String msg_id_us = msgList.getString("msg_id_user");

                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put(LV_MSGID, msg_id);
                map.put(LV_MSG, msg);
                map.put(LV_USID_MSG, msg_id_us);
                data.add(map);
            }

            String[] from = { LV_MSGID, LV_MSG, LV_USID_MSG };
            int   [] to   = { R.id.id_msg, R.id.msg, R.id.id_msg_user };

            sAdapter = new FriendMsgLoad.ChatAdapter(FriendMsgActivity.this, data, R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, from, to);
            sList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFriendMsg);
            sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);
            sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    class ChatAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            View v = convertView;
            HashMap < String, String > item = (HashMap < String, String > ) sList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String msg = item.get(LV_MSG);

            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, null);

                    TextView myText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
                    myText.setText(msg);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talker, null);

                    TextView otherText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
                    otherText.setText(msg);
                    break;
                default:

            }
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
            HashMap < String, String > item = (HashMap < String, String > ) sList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int myIDfromList = Integer.parseInt(item.get(LV_USID_MSG));
            return myIDfromList;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Хендлер у вас да, каждые 10 секунд срабатывает, а вот задачу вы всего раз запускаете. Как же может быть иначе, если в хэндлере вы не делаете ничего кроме вывода в логи?..

Comment: Спасибо большое...надо было всего лишь изъять метод `new FriendMsgLoad().execute();` и поместить его в handler :)

Comment: Я написал это в ответ и вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа

Comment: Также это увеличит вам репутацию и даст ачивку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хендлер у вас да, каждые 10 секунд срабатывает, а вот задачу вы всего раз запускаете. Как же может быть иначе, если в хэндлере вы не делаете ничего кроме вывода в логи?..

Т.е. вам надо поместить вызов вашего сетевого запроса внутрь метода run вашего handler-а

```
class RefreshActivity extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FriendMsgActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Сработал mHandler!");
                //запускаем сетевой запрос
                new FriendMsgLoad().execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему теперь ListView, постоянно возвращается в исходную позицию? В таком случае, надо сохранять текущую позицию скролла а потом восстанавливать? Как в таком случае правильно поступить?

Comment: @sergei1094, вы каждый раз заново создаёте и устанавливаете адаптер. По идее, вам надо только менять набор данных для адаптера и уведомлять оный об изменениях в нём

Comment: У вас нет случайно примеров реализации?

Comment: Сейчас я хочу попробовать сделать так: `Если, ListView, не путой`, и ID последнего сообщения изменился на сервере, то получить данные о сообщении и добавить их в МАП. `Иначе, sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);`. Будет ли это верным решением?

Comment: @sergei1094, сложно что-то определённое сказать - в зависимости от потребностей и логики может потребоваться разный код и разные подходы. Вам лучше задать отдельный вопрос. Только не выкладывайте сразу весь код. В данном вопросе, например, 90% кода были просто лишними